# Webservices with Authentik forward auth behind Nginx Proxy Manager and CORS

Tags: authentication, nginx, cors, reverse-proxy

I'm having some trouble setting up the Nginx Proxy Manager for proxy authentication through Authentik for my webservices without incurring in **CORS**.

I have a NPM host for my dashboard at dashboard.website.com (https://gethomepage.dev/latest/)

[image]

This is the custom configuration of the host

```
# Increase buffer size for large headers
# This is needed only if you get 'upstream sent too big header while reading response
# header from upstream' error when trying to access an application protected by goauthentik
proxy_buffers 8 16k;
proxy_buffer_size 32k;

# Make sure not to redirect traffic to a port 4443
port_in_redirect off;

location / {
    # Put your proxy_pass to your application here
    proxy_pass $forward_scheme://$server:$port;
    
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
    
    # Set any other headers your application might need
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    add_header "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" $http_origin always;
    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' 'true';

    ##############################
    # authentik-specific config
    ##############################
    auth_request /outpost.goauthentik.io/auth/nginx;
    error_page 401 = @goauthentik_proxy_signin;
    auth_request_set $auth_cookie $upstream_http_set_cookie;
    add_header Set-Cookie $auth_cookie;

    # translate headers from the outposts back to the actual upstream
    auth_request_set $authentik_username $upstream_http_x_authentik_username;
    auth_request_set $authentik_groups $upstream_http_x_authentik_groups;
    auth_request_set $authentik_email $upstream_http_x_authentik_email;
    auth_request_set $authentik_name $upstream_http_x_authentik_name;
    auth_request_set $authentik_uid $upstream_http_x_authentik_uid;

    proxy_set_header X-authentik-username $authentik_username;
    proxy_set_header X-authentik-groups $authentik_groups;
    proxy_set_header X-authentik-email $authentik_email;
    proxy_set_header X-authentik-name $authentik_name;
    proxy_set_header X-authentik-uid $authentik_uid;
}

# all requests to /outpost.goauthentik.io must be accessible without authentication
location /outpost.goauthentik.io {
    proxy_pass http://192.168.1.139:5080/outpost.goauthentik.io;
    # ensure the host of this vserver matches your external URL you've configured
    # in authentik
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Original-URL $scheme://$http_host$request_uri;
    add_header Set-Cookie $auth_cookie;
    auth_request_set $auth_cookie $upstream_http_set_cookie;

    proxy_pass_request_body off;
    proxy_set_header Content-Length "";
}

# Special location for when the /auth endpoint returns a 401,
# redirect to the /start URL which initiates SSO
location @goauthentik_proxy_signin {
    internal;
    add_header Set-Cookie $auth_cookie;
    return 302 /outpost.goauthentik.io/start?rd=$scheme://$http_host$request_uri;
    # For domain level, use the below error_page to redirect to your authentik server with the full redirect path
    # return 302 https://authentik.company/outpost.goauthentik.io/start?rd=$scheme://$http_host$request_uri;
}
```

In Authentik I have the dashboard application, the provider setup with default-authentication-flow and default-provider-authorization-implicit-consent (Authorize Application) for forward auth (domain level) on website.com, and the default authentik outpost for all my proxy providers.

## **First issue**

When I go to dashboard.website.com it asks me for authentication in authentik, and then redirects me to the website, but I see a list of error messages in the console about CORS, and causing "API errors" from Homepage.

> Access to fetch at 'https://auth.website.com/application/o/authorize/?client_id=xxxx&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fnginx.website.com%2Foutpost.goauthentik.io%2Fcallback%3FX-authentik-auth-callback%3Dtrue&response_type=code&scope=email+ak_proxy+openid+profile&state=xxxxxxx-k' (redirected from 'https://dashboard.website.com/api/hash') from origin 'https://dashboard.website.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

## **Second issue**

Another problem I have is that *sometimes* when refreshing I get randomly  redirected (passing through Authentik) to some of the URI that the webpage is trying to reach (for example to https://dashboard.website.com/api/bookmarks)

## **Third issue**

When login through Authentik the login page tells me "Login to continue to nginx", but I want it to tell me the webservice I'm trying to reach. What can I do to fix this?

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

I already added

```
    add_header "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" $http_origin always;
    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' 'true';
```

to the dashboard host but it's the first time I'm using Nginx and I'm not familiar with its configurations and how it should works. I presumed I had to add the Access-Control-Allow-Origin headers to my auth route but I didn't success in making it works without a 500 error.